# Interceptor not working in Spring Boot GraphQL

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, graphql, interceptor

Im using graphql-java-kickstart/graphql-spring-boot and I'd like to create an interceptor to add an HTTP header after processing the request.

When I'm sending a graphql request to the backend the the interceptor is not triggered. But some calls trigger the interceptor. For example when I'm opening /graphiql in my browser I see that the interceptor is triggered but when I send a graphql request from graphiql client it is not. Any idea why? Anybody got experience with this?

My config looks like this:

```
@Configuration
public class InterceptorConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Autowired
    private TestInterceptor testInterceptor;

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(testInterceptor).addPathPatterns("/**");
    }
}
```

Also my Interceptor:

```
@Slf4j
@Component
public class TestInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {

    @Override
    public void postHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, ModelAndView modelAndView)
            throws Exception {
        // post processing
        log.info("hello there");
    }

}
```

Comment: https://github.com/graphql-java-kickstart/graphql-spring-boot/issues/120

Comment: Thanks for the link I found that issue too. A contributor says "... I would say that a correct configuration of those interceptors should work..." but all the comments are about ServletListeners and Filters which wont't do the task for me.

Comment: Sounds like it might be related to the the path in your pattern. Could you try to send a request from the client using the same path?

Answer (score 1):

I have following interceptor that successfully works in my project:

1. My WebConfig:

```java
@Configuration
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    
    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(requestInterceptor);
    }
    
    @Autowired
    private ControllerExecInterceptor requestInterceptor;
}
```

Where ControllerExecInterceptor defined as:

```java
@Component
public class ControllerExecInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {
    
    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws AccessDeniedException, Exception {
        // ...
    }

    @Override
    public boolean postHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse 
                            response, Object handler) throws {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it a graphql API or REST?

Comment: This configuration is for REST, but you could thy maybe it would work with GraphQL

Comment: Looks like it works with GraphQL too. Thanks.

Comment: "HandlerInterceptorAdapter" is deprecated, use implements HandlerInterceptor instead.